# TestinTaskFramework.Framework for game development

Tags: c#, game-engine, monogame, sharpdx

```
[STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int seed = 0;
            if (args.Length > 0)
            int.TryParse(args[0], out seed);
             Framework.Run(new ShipBehavior(), new World(), seed); // exception

        }
```

**EXCEPTION:** `"An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.Direct3D9.dll"`

I am using `VRAGE` Libraries and `TestingTaskFramework` dll file which contains this Framework class and `Framework.Run()` function.

Comment: What does the exception say, is there any message or inner exception?
Also check out Output window in Visual Studio for more info.

Comment: EXCEPTION: "An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.Direct3D9.dll".

Comment: post the code for `ShipBehavior` also maybe post the places where you got the Vrage and TestingTaskFramework.